# AngularJS and using $timeout to render template

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am trying to render/return the content within this directive after 1 second.  Tried multiple ways of doing this but can't seem to get it working and I have a gut feeling that it should be super easy.  Below is an example of my code.  Corrections to my code would be greatly appreciated!

The Directive:

```
myApp.directive("helloWorld", ['$timeout', $timeout(function() {
    return {
    restrict: "E",
    template: '<h1>Hello World!</h1>'
    };
}, 1000)]);
```

HTML-partial view code Calling the above Directive:

```
<hello-World/>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the directives controller to set a "show something variable" after a timeout

```
myApp.directive("helloWorld", ['$timeout', (function($timeout) {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        template: '<h1 data-ng-show="showData">Hello World!</h1>',
        controller: function($scope, $timeout) {
            $scope.showData = false;
            $timeout(function() {
                $scope.showData = true;
            }, 1000);
        }
    };
})]);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2om8ybhy/